# Not able to create dynamic tables using Entity Framework with a code-first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create tables dynamically using Entity Framework with a code-first approach. I am dynamically creating class using the `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace. I am able to add `[Table]` attribute to class and was also able to add [Key] attribute to a int property. When I try to create table it throws exception that the class has no key defined.

My questions:

1. Is it mandatory to have a `KeyAttribute`?
2. What is wrong with my code?

I tried to debug and try to find attributes attached to that property and it shows that there are no attributes added but it has custom attribute of type `KeyAttribute`.

I have statically defined class with `KeyAttribute` added to one of the property. When I debug that the `KeyAttribute` was not added in `Attributes` collection. It was there is `GetCustomAttributes()`

Create class, add int property and add `KeyAttribute` using `System.Reflection.Emit`:

```
public Type CreateClass(string className)
{
        Type returnValue = null;
        currentClassBuilder = currentModuleBuilder.DefineType(className, TypeAttributes.Public);
        AddTableAttributeToProperty(className);
        AddDefaultConstructor();
        FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = AddField("m_Number", typeof(Int32));
        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = AddProperty("Number", typeof(Int32));
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(AddSetMethod(fieldBuilder, typeof(int)));
        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(AddSetMethod(fieldBuilder, typeof(int)));
        AddKeyAttributeToProperty(propertyBuilder);
        returnValue = currentClassBuilder.CreateType();
        return returnValue;
 }
```

In `DbContext` class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        var entityMethod = typeof(DbModelBuilder).GetMethod("Entity");

        foreach (var assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            var entityTypes = assembly
              .GetTypes()
              .Where(t =>
                t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), inherit: true)
                .Any());

            foreach (var type in entityTypes)
            {
                entityMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type)
                  .Invoke(modelBuilder, new object[] { });
            }
        }
}
```